# Python Popen wait/poll blocking execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I need to execute a exe file with arguments which reads a file, makes some calculations and generates 3 new files. Using `subprocess.Popen` works fine. But in order to check it's execution, I'm using `wait()`. But when `wait()` is used, the process doesn't work and no files are generated. I even checked in task manager. It generally takes 5 seconds for the process to complete, but if `wait()` is used, the process ends within a second. Can anyone help me out?

```
process = subprocess.Popen(span_command, shell=True)
```

The above snippet when used alone works fine, but if used with `process.wait()`, the process stops.

Comment: Did you check `process.returncode`?

Comment: @Frane Its returning None, but my files are generating. If I use `process.communicate()` then the execution stops and no files are generating.

Comment: `returncode ==  None` means process is not finished. You probably checked it without `process.wait()`.  What happens when you run span_command directly in shell? Does it ever finish or it's waiting for some input? Why you use `shell=True` mostly it's not needed?

Comment: @Frane If I use `process.wait()`, process runs but files are not generated. But `process.returncode` returns 0 after using `process.wait()`. Using span_command directly in shell works fine. Using span_command without `shell=True` is also not working.

Comment: I would say it's something with program you are running as subprocess. Maybe in combination with OS you are using.
Did you try using `subprocess.run`?

Comment: @Frane I tried `suprocess.run` and `subprocess.call` too but its not working. I am using Windows. Using `process.wait()` is stopping the program from executing. When the same program is executed from Command line t works smoothly

Comment: @dbamistry: This doesn't seem like it should be possible to go wrong; [all `wait` does on Windows is call `WaitForSingleObject` on the process handle](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/subprocess.py#L1229), then once that returns (indicating the process exited), it calls `GetExitCodeProcess` to populate `returnvalue`. Neither one should cause the process to behave differently in the general case. You're going to need to provide more information on your code and the program it's trying to run, because this should just work under normal conditions.

Comment: Given that `WaitForSingleObject` is Windows' standard means of waiting for a process to exit (their [example code for creating/waiting on processes uses it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/creating-processes)), this should just work under normal conditions. [There are some potential deadlocks in a GUI program from using it](https://marc.durdin.net/2012/08/waitforsingleobject-why-you-should-never-use-it/), but the symptom there would be deadlock, not early exit, and you've given no indication that your script is GUI-based.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The program takes a file as input and generates new files. When executed from CMD directly, it works. Even in python it works if `subprocess.Popen()` is the last command. Any code written after that except print results in early exit of the program. It can be accessed using GUI too.

Answer (score -1):

More information regarding executed program is needed.

I think that yours program ends when it's `stdin` is closed.

For example `date` on windows expects input and finishes when it receives some input.

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["date"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE ,shell=True)
print(p2.returncode)
time.sleep(10)
print(p2.returncode)
print(p2.wait())
print(p2.returncode)
```

This could be solution for you. Wait some time before calling `wait`.

But it would be better to know how that program reacts on different inputs and run with `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` and `p2.communicate("some expected input")`.

Check output of program you are running.

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["date"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE ,shell=True)
print(p2.wait())
print(p2.stdout.readlines())
print(p2.stderr.readlines())
```

It's not solution, it's debugging process.

There is no reason not to work in code you have given. 
So it's something you didn't show us. First suspect is program you are running.

Comment: I've tried using all of these above. `time.sleep(10)` causes the process to end from task manager and I don't get desired output. My program requires path of a file for execution which is passed in `span_command` itself. The entire `span_command` works fine when executed directly from command line. The problem is that after subprocess starts, if any code is written after that, subprocess stops and the code executes further. Only printing works. The same program is running in PHP using `exec()` function.

Comment: Did you try same with some other program?
You can also try looking into `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`

Comment: @dbamistry stdout and stderr might give you more information what went wrong.
It's not solution, it's debugging process.

There is no reason not to work in code you have given. So it's something you didn't show us. First suspect is program you are running.

Comment: `proc.wait()` is returning 0. `stdout` is returning `<_io.BufferedReader name=6>` and `stderr` `<_io.BufferedReader name=7>`. The software is a GUI based software which takes a file as input and generates few files. We can access it from CMD too and the syntax works fine in CMD.

Comment: `stderr.readlines()` is empty. I believe no errors. `stdout.readlines()` is data from input file.

Comment: Is there difference between  `stdout.readlines()` and output when run in shell?
Did you check how does some other program behaves if run same way?
You say that without `wait()` program finishes correctly. How can you tell?

Comment: I'm checking it in Windows task manager. And when the execution finishes, 3 files are generated. With `wait()`, no files are generated and the execution lasts only a second in task manager.

Comment: Can you show your `span_command`?
Also I would try pressing enter several times right after starting program in command line shell.

Comment: This is `span_command` : `C:\SPAN\Span4\Bin\spanit "C:\xampp\htdocs\span_webservice\files\NSE_FUTURES_script.txt" > C:\SPAN\Span4\spanit.log`. `spanit` is the exe and the next parameter is the path of the file which acts as inout. I tried pressing enter several times in command line, but it worked.

Comment: Command is string, not array?
Try `span_command = ['C:\\SPAN\\Span4\\Bin\\spanit', '"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\span_webservice\\files\\NSE_FUTURES_script.txt"']` with `shell=False` and `stdout=open('C:\\SPAN\\Span4\\spanit.log',"w+")`.

Comment: Did you try running some other program, to check if there is some issue with your python installation? Or on different computer?

Comment: From the beginning I suspect it something with STDIN of given program but you didn't try to leave it open. Include `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` in parameters and see if there is difference with or without `wait`.